# System clock seems fine, logs timestamp however are not

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logging

Managing remotely my VPS, I wanted the logs and everything written in my timezone so I could read easily when something happened.

So I changed the timezone and now "date" command and such returns my local time, not server's local time.

But guess what, all logs timestamp with server's local time. What did I miss? Do I have to restart logs or something?

```
carles@Central:~$ date
Mon Sep  1 00:28:53 CEST 2014

carles@Central:~$ sudo tail -n 1 /var/log/auth.log
Aug 31 22:29:37 Central sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by carles(uid=0)

carles@Central:~$ uname -a
Linux Central 3.15.4-x86_64-linode45 #1 SMP Mon Jul 7 08:42:36 EDT 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: TZ for the login user, TZ for the system, and TZ for root are 3 different things.

Comment: Thanks, any manual touching those three?